Theme - requires a dependency "magento/framework" cannot be found
I've begun working on a theme for Magento 2. I'm new to this so go easy.
I've been following along with the documentation Create a Storefront Theme | Commerce Frontend Development and I want to add an additional dependency via composer.
However if try composer require mindplay/php-vite for example composer throws an error
Root composer.json requires magento/framework, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

This strikes me as odd as blank/luma and the docs reference magento/framework as a requirement for a theme in composer.json.
Is there a private registry or something I need to add as there is no magento/framework on Packagist.
Am I missing something?
{
    "name": "oliware/theme-frontend-bumblebee",
    "description": "N/A",
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "0.0.2-alpha",
    "require": {
        "php": "~8.1.0||~8.2.0||~8.3.0",
        "magento/framework": "103.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}

It's worth noting I am working with a git cloned version of the magento2 repo and developing the theme that way.

check if you have auth.json file present in your root,

when adding dependency through composer, you need auth keys to be present in your project root folder.

Seems like it's your whole magento who is not properly installed; if you have magento installed then you should have magento/framework in the vendor.
First thing ; check your auth.json file and make you your magento 2 keys are registredred there
{
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "XXXXX",
        "password": "YYYYY"
    }
}
}

Then go to check your composer.json if you are requesting magento
In repositories you should have magento
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }

And obviously all the dependence you need like
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",

If all that is fine, when you run composer install then the magento/framework should be in the vendor.

I think you might be right. I have done my magento installation a bunch of times with different setups and I think I am missing the auth.json! I'll give it a go and mark as the answer if that was the issue. I though there may be a private registry!

I am marking this as the answer., however, I think the answer lacks a little detail. There are really two parts, 1) you need to configure the magento repository in the composer.json file you want to use require on. 2) you need the auth.json to authenticate with the repository.
In my case these were within my theme directory app/design/<Vendor>/<theme>
